# Merge the same column in two pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to merge the same `Result` column in two pandas dataframes. The 'Result` column is not expected to populated with contradicting value. Both dataframes have two columns `id` and `sub_id` as the unique identifier.

The first dataframe would look like such:

```
   id sub_id           Result
0  G1     00              
1  G1     F1  under-reporting
2  G2     N1  under-reporting
```

And the second dataframe would look like such:

```
   id sub_id           Result
0  G3     W1   over-reporting         
1  G3     00   over-reporting          
2  G4     K5
```

If the record is not populated with either `under-reporting` or `over-reporting`, I would like to populate that record with the string `pass`.
As result, I would like the output look like such:

```
   id sub_id           Result
0  G1     00             Pass   
1  G1     F1  under-reporting
2  G2     N1  under-reporting
3  G3     W1   over-reporting          
4  G3     00   over-reporting            
5  G4     K5             Pass
```

Below is the code I am applying right now:

```
#User a jointed mask to filter reportable deals
reportable_deals = df[joint_logic_of_reportable_deals]
under_reporting_df = reportable_deals[['id', 'sub_id']].copy()

#User left merge to identify under-reporting deals (i.e., reportable deals not in the trade_state_df)
under_reporting_df = under_reporting_df.merge(trade_state_df, how='left', on=['id', 'sub_id'], indicator='Result')

under_reporting_df['Result'] = under_reporting_df['Result'].map({
    'both': np.nan,
    'left_only': 'under-reporting',
    'right_only': np.nan
})

#Obtain not-reportable deals using the inverse of the jointed mask
not_reportable_deals = df_data_store[~joint_logic_of_reportable_deals]
over_reporting_df = not_reportable_deals[['id', 'sub_id']].copy()

over_reporting_df['sub_id'] = over_reporting_df['sub_id'].astype(str).str.zfill(2)

#User the left merge to identify over-reporting deals (i.e., not-reportable but exists in the trade_state_df)
over_reporting_df = over_reporting_df.merge(trade_state_df, how='left', on=['id', 'sub_id'], indicator='Result')

over_reporting_df['Result'] = (over_reporting_df['Result'] == 'both')
over_reporting_df['Result'] = np.where(over_reporting_df['Result'], 'over-reporting', np.nan)

output_df = pd.concat([under_reporting_df, over_reporting_df])
output_df = output_df.reset_index(drop=True)
header = ['id', 'sub_id', 'Result']
output_df.to_csv("Eligibility Result.csv", columns = header)
```

However, the issue is that after the `concat` method, the `output_df` now has 7 more deals than the original `df`
Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: What have you tried so far and what went wrong with your attempts?

Comment: That should be a simple join of the two (on `id` and `sub_id`) and then you can edit missing values to be "Pass".

Comment: @andrewb would you mind elaborating more on how to use the join method?

Comment: It would be much easier if you provided the source code for the data

Comment: @sammywemmy thank you so much for the suggestion. I just added the source code in and it is a lot of code. So thats why I did not add in the first place

Comment: could you just do `pd.concat([df1,df2]).fillna('pass')`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming missing values are 'NaN', you can try fillna:

```
(df1.set_index(["id", 'sub_id'])
    .fillna(df2.set_index(["id", 'sub_id']))
    .fillna("pass")
    .reset_index())
```

Result

```
    id  sub_id  Result
0   G1  00  over-reporting
1   G1  F1  under-reporting
2   G2  N1  under-reporting
3   G3  W1  pass
4   G3  00  pass
5   G4  K5  over-reporting
```

Comment: I would get ```InvalidIndexError``` error on the first line though